# Change color of all lines on a design

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path, shapes

I was working on a project and all of a sudden out of nowhere, all of my lines on the project turned black from white and I have had no success in changing them back to white again.

how do you change all the lines on a project to white?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different ways to do that, but first make sure you don't have any locked objects or layers. Then either:

- hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select everything
- OR: select one of the objects (what you call *"lines"* are actually called objects), and then go to *Select → Same → Stroke Color*
- THEN: select the *Stroke* from the *Window → Color* panel, and click the *white* box

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that